# TypeError: Attempting to change value of a readonly property. defineProperty

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, keyboard-events

I am trying *window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent)*.

I am doing this to catch *keyboardevent's* keycode value and will perform some operation based on which key is pressed. Without this keycode is coming as 0 even when i am running in browser.

My code goes something like

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
                    var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
                    var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
                    keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                                   "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                                    true, // bubbles
                                    true, // cancelable
                                    window, // viewArg: should be window
                                    false, // ctrlKeyArg
                                    false, // altKeyArg
                                    false, // shiftKeyArg
                                    false, // metaKeyArg
                                    666, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                                    null // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
                    );
                    delete keyboardEvent.keyCode;
                    Object.defineProperty(keyboardEvent, "keyCode", {"value" : 666});
                    window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
                }, 10000);
```

*i am giving value 666 just to test.*

This works fine when i run it in chrome.

but this line of code

```
Object.defineProperty(keyboardEvent, "keyCode", {"value" : 666});
```

thorws "TypeError: Attempting to change value of a readonly property. defineProperty." when i run code in set top box.

this is `plnkr` link for above code http://plnkr.co/edit/my8HkFpRqZRDrFYgIxXL?p=preview

How can I capture correct keycode in set top box so I can automate key press event?
Can any extra line be added/modified to above code that will give correct key code on set top box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I found [this link](http://output.jsbin.com/awenaq/3) which is solving this problem.

Set top box is using `webkit` to run JavaScript code and when `keyboardEvent` is registered and `dispatchEvent` is called over that for any key press, webkit gives `keyCode` as 0 for any `keyboardEvent`.

To overcome this problem, instead of using `keyboardEvent` use generic event to programmatically triggering events.

Code can be seen in [this link](http://output.jsbin.com/awenaq/3). Here function `__triggerKeyboardEvent` is using generic event to programmatically trigger event.

It works perfectly in set top box.